# Nhibernate order by nested object property

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want sort my data based upon a property of anested object.

This is the main class "Bulletin":

```
[Serializable]
public class Bulletin
{
    public virtual Int32 BulletinID { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 AgentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipient Recipient
    {
        get
        {
            var rm = new CRecipientManager();
            var rec = rm.GetById(1);
            return rec;
        }
    }
    public virtual DateTime? DateSent { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateEntry { get; set; }
}
```

the hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Sfa.Engine.domain.Bulletin,Sfa.Engine" table="Bulletins" lazy="true">
    <id name="BulletinID" column="BulletinID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="AgentID" column="AgentID" type="Int32" not-null="true" />   
    <property name="DateSent" column="DateSent" type="datetime" not-null="false" />
    <property name="DateEntry" column="DateEntry" type="datetime" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the second one "Recipient":

```
public class Recipient
{
    public virtual Int32 RecipientID { get; set; }
    public virtual String Prefix { get; set; }
    public virtual String Firstname { get; set; }
    public virtual String Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual String Email { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateEntry { get; set; }
}
```

My manager code:

```
public ICollection<Bulletin> GetAll()
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        var bulletins = session
            .CreateCriteria(typeof(Bulletin))
            .AddOrder(Order.Asc("BulletinID"))
            .CreateAlias("Recipient", "rec").AddOrder(Order.Asc("rec.Firstname"))
            .List<Bulletin>();
        return bulletins;
    }
}
```

I created an alias of the class Recipient and used the Firstname as sort criteria but nhibernate give me this:
**could not resolve property: Recipient of: Sfa.Engine.domain.Bulletin**

The Recipient propery of Bulletin object is accessible and public, what's wrong?

Comment: Actually in the hbm.xml of the main class, "Bulletin", there is no items referring to the object Recipient. Could be this normal? or must I map the relation as one-to-one?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
    public ICollection<Bulletin> GetAll()
    {
        using (ISession session = null)
        {
            var bulletins = session
                .CreateCriteria(typeof(Bulletin))
                .CreateAlias("Recipient", "rec")
                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.Property("rec.Firstname"), "Firstname")
                )
                .AddOrder(Order.Asc("BulletinID"))
                .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Firstname"))
                .List<Bulletin>();
            return bulletins;
        }
    }
```

See [this](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html)

Comment: Where do you inizialize the ISession object? If I tun this code, the session obj is null, but if I initialize using NHibernateHelper.OpenSession() I got the same error I mentioned above